# can someone explain to me why there is a zero inside after the compareTo expression.. thank you

Tags: c#

what is the zero in the expression for?

```
    public void Insert(TItem newItem)
    {
        TItem currentNodeValue = this.NodeData;
        if (currentNodeValue.CompareTo(newItem) > 0) 
        {
           // insert new item into the left subtree
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could easily find out by running the code in a debugger

Comment: > =  <  Greater, equal, less 1, 0, -1

Comment: Or by having a quick look at the [**official documentation**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compareto?view=net-6.0) of the `CompareTo` method - it's all explained, you know - you just need to **look it up**

Answer (score 0):

The `CompareTo` method is probably returning an `int` value and you are checking to see if that value is greater than `0`.
If so, based on what you have, you would insert new item to the left subtree.